# Building web assembly with bazel and emscripten

Tags: c++, llvm, bazel, emscripten, webassembly

I've been trying to build a simple c++ in webassembly with Bazel, by following the [doc from bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html) but I can't manage to make it work.

Everything works well, bazel manages to download the emscripten packages, start the build and suddenly says that he cannot find the sources...

```
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
Loading:
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (5 packages loaded, 16 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (11 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (11 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (11 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (11 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (11 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (11 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (11 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
INFO: SHA256 (https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/archive/1.37.22.tar.gz) = 433dedb63ba423cf04bbc9802b49fa842bd479bad31a339db9506614e92334c7
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (11 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
DEBUG: Rule 'emscripten_toolchain' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "433dedb63ba423cf04bbc9802b49fa842bd479bad31a339db9506614e92334c7"
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (12 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (12 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (12 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (12 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (12 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (12 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
INFO: SHA256 (https://s3.amazonaws.com/mozilla-games/emscripten/packages/llvm/tag/linux_64bit/emscripten-llvm-e1.37.22.tar.gz) = fd457ebfbe5a727058880ff55cdabf7f1b7809aea07957d2cc854e7de3001ef3
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (12 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //main:helloworld (12 packages loaded, 59 targets configured)
DEBUG: Rule 'emscripten_clang' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "fd457ebfbe5a727058880ff55cdabf7f1b7809aea07957d2cc854e7de3001ef3"
INFO: Analyzed target //main:helloworld (13 packages loaded, 7624 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[0 / 3] [Prepa] Creating source manifest for //main:helloworld ... (2 actions, 0 running)
[0 / 3] [Prepa] Creating source manifest for //main:helloworld ... (2 actions, 0 running)
[3 / 5] checking cached actions
ERROR: /usr/src/app/main/BUILD:1:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//main:helloworld':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'main/hello-world.cc':
  '/usr/src/app/main/hello-world.cc'
DEBUG:root:PYTHON not defined in /root/.emscripten, using "/usr/bin/python"
DEBUG:root:EMCC_WASM_BACKEND tells us to use wasm backend
WARNING:root:invocation: external/emscripten_toolchain/emcc.py -MD -MF bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/helloworld/hello-world.d -frandom-seed=bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/helloworld/hello-world.o -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools -isystem external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include/libcxx -isystem external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include/libc -c main/hello-world.cc -o bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/helloworld/hello-world.o  (in /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/sandbox/processwrapper-sandbox/1/execroot/__main__)
DEBUG:root:compiling to bitcode
DEBUG:root:emcc step "parse arguments and setup" took 0.00 seconds
DEBUG:root:compiling source file: /usr/src/app/main/hello-world.cc
DEBUG:root:running: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_clang/clang++ -target wasm32-unknown-unknown -D__EMSCRIPTEN_major__=1 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_minor__=37 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_tiny__=22 -D_LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION=2 -D__EMSCRIPTEN__ -Dunix -D__unix -D__unix__ -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -nostdinc -Xclang -nobuiltininc -Xclang -nostdsysteminc -Xclang -isystem/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include/libcxx -Xclang -isystem/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_toolchain/system/lib/libcxxabi/include -Xclang -isystem/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include/compat -Xclang -isystem/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include -Xclang -isystem/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include/SSE -Xclang -isystem/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include/libc -Xclang -isystem/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_toolchain/system/lib/libc/musl/arch/emscripten -Xclang -isystem/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_toolchain/system/local/include -MD -MF bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/helloworld/hello-world.d -frandom-seed=bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/helloworld/hello-world.o -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools -isystem external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include/libcxx -isystem external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include/libc -c -std=c++03 /usr/src/app/main/hello-world.cc -Xclang -isystem/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/a14564dce24fc232216f1aef117728d1/external/emscripten_toolchain/system/include/SDL -emit-llvm -c -o bazel-out/asmjs-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/helloworld/hello-world.o
DEBUG:root:emcc step "bitcodeize inputs" took 0.01 seconds
DEBUG:root:stopping at bitcode
Target //main:helloworld failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 60.763s, Critical Path: 0.67s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I wrapped everything in [a github repository](https://github.com/jdrouet/bazel-emscripten-test) and you can reproduce this (if you have docker installed) by doing

```
git clone https://github.com/jdrouet/bazel-emscripten-test.git
cd bazel-emscripten-test
docker build .
```

If you have any idea of why this doesn't work, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The .d (dependency) files generated by emscripten do not play nice with bazel. The tutorial 'fixes' this by adding `find . -name "*.d" -exec sed -i '2d' {} \;` (which removes the first line of the dependency list). You did not include this line in your github project, which is why you experienced this issue.

The reason emscripten's dependency files don't play nice with bazel is because they use absolute paths not relative ones and hence refer to files bazel thinks does not exist.

After you've fixed this issue and have decided to build a more complex project you would also encounter additional dependency issues where other lines than the first start with / in the .d file. I had to create a script to remove all lines starting with / from a file because I'm not a bash wizard. You can find my code [here](https://github.com/gaycodegal/operator-12/blob/opengl/wasm_toolchain/dependency_cleaner.py).

You will also run into the issue that the tutorial doesn't handle linking of cc_library rules well so you'll need to make a emar.sh (and link it into the crosstool). [This](https://github.com/gaycodegal/operator-12/blob/opengl/wasm_toolchain/emar.sh) is what i did.

You'll finally in more complex projects run into an issue where bazel complains when you try to link against a library it has to compile on its own like SDL. <strike>For this I have yet to find a permanent solution, but if you have already compiled projects without bazel that link against these same libraries and have your global emscripten_cache symlinked into your bazel project, the build will succeed without complaint. I have yet to figure out how to get bazel to build successfully from an empty cache when linking against SDL unfortunately.</strike>

Edit:
You can create a full cache by using `python embuilder.py build ALL`, or specify individual required targets. I personally added a call like that with the required targets into a repository rule, but it is extremely specific to my project and I decided to pull information from environment variables so I will not include it in this answer. Knowing about `embuilder.py` is really all you need for your own implmentation.